# pivottable.js Aggregator

Tags: javascript, jquery, pivottable.js

I'm using the pivottable.js plugin [here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable).

pivottable.js aggregator [documentation](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Aggregators).

I want to to use my data for "Users" as the value in the pivot table cells. Right now I am accessing user data from my info[] array. I also have it set as a "row" value currently. I want to modify this so that "Users" will be my VALUE in the cells of the table.

```
function refreshTable(){

console.log("Starting Pivot Table Population");

//ajax start
$.get(
    "table.php",
    function(data){

        //loop through the data and feed to the pivotUI
        var info = [];
        for (var ii=0; ii < array.length; ii++) {
            info.push({
                Skill: array[ii][0],
                Users: array[ii][3],
                IOT: array[ii][1],
                IMT: array[ii][2],
                Level: array[ii][4]});
        }
        console.log(info);

        //pivot UI
        $('#output').show();
        $("#output").pivotUI(
            info,
            {
                rows: ["Row","Users"],
                cols: ["Col1","Col2","Col3"]
            }
        );
     }

        //end of ajax function "TYPE"
        , "json")
};
```

Comment: FYI : this library is not called `pivot.js` but rather `pivottable.js`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `vals` parameter, as documented here: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Parameters#pivotuiinput-options-overwrite-locale